# Амперсанд в параметрах функции

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как это работает? Допустим, имеется такая функция:

```
void foo(int &one, int two){
    one = two;
}

int s1 = 1;
int s2 = 2;
foo(s1, s2);
```

Как работает амперсанд перед параметром функции `one`? Я понимаю, что функция работает с переменной, которая выделена в статической памяти. Выходит, что мы передаем в функцию значение типа `int`, затем берем его адрес. Но почему в теле функции можем работать с ним как с обычной переменной, а не как с указателем? По идее, нужно было бы разыменовывать.

Такая конструкция понятна:

```
void foo(int* one, int two)
{ 
   *one = two;
}
```

и при вызове функции передаем так параметры `(&s1, s2);`.

Comment: Так то под капотом, считай указатель передается в итоге.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А потому и пишем `&`, чтобы можно было писать `one = two`, а не `*one = two`. Тут вся суть в том, что явно указатель передают когда хотят работать непосредственно с ним, когда нужно знать его значение. Когда же мы хотим работать со значением переменной, но не только в функции в которой она создана, но и в «потомственных», то мы передаём её по ссылке.

Вы конечно можете сказать что-нибудь типа «мне это непривычно, я лучше буду передавать адреса явно», но поверьте — передача переменной по ссылке в случае, если надо работать с самой переменной — правильный подход к программированию. Хороший программист обязан уметь писать ХОРОШИЙ код — не только алгоритмически эффективный, но и максимально понятный; такой, чтобы его суть была понятна другому программисту, даже впервые его увидевшему.

В языке C# передача переменной по ссылке выглядит более красиво, там просто и в вызывающем, и в вызываемом методах перед переменной пишется слово `ref` (или `out`, что идёт там по смыслу «дополнительное возвращаемое значение»).

Comment: @Skripkin90, передача параметра по ссылке весьма неудачное проектное решение в крестах, часто затрудняющее поиск ошибок (в чужих программах). 

Если параметр может меняться в вызываемой функции, то лучше явно передавать адрес.

--

Недаром Вы привели пример с C# (ref в обоих методах).

Comment: аа, вы имеете ввиду что под дебагом чужого коды вы проходите функцию ошибочно полагая что в ней параметр передаётся копированием, а там в действительности параметр передаётся по ссылке, и... ну в общем бяка, теряете нити при отладке? 
Даа, да вы правы это действительно может очень сильно затруднить дебаг чужого кода... Да.
Я просто на шарпе пишу.

Comment: @avp зато `const Foo& foo` позволит не проверять на `nullptr`, с `const Foo* foo` так бы не прокатило.

Answer (score 2):

почитайте код ниже, думаю разберетесь

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int value = 0; // переменная инициализированная нулем

    cout << value << endl; // выведет нуль

    int & link = value; // ссылка на переменную (не может существовать без указания имени переменной)

    link = 100; // через ссылку записываем в переменную значение 100

    cout << value << endl; // выведет 100

    return 0;
}
```

тоже самое происходит и при передачи ссылки в функцию. ссылка - это всего лишь второе имя переменной (псефдоним)